# Reuse SVG elements with different path values

Tags: html, svg

I need to make circle sectors like shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2YxdK/) , however i'd like to define the sector svg once and then reuse it with different values for d in path. Something like

```
<svg>
   <defs id="circle>
      <g>
         <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="110"></circle>
         <path d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 225,115 z"></path>
         <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="50"></circle>
      </g>
   </defs>
</svg>

<svg>
    <use d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 115,125 A110,110 1 0,1 35,190 z" xlink:href = "#circle/>
</svg>
<svg>
     <use d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 115,225 A110,110 1 0,1 35,190 z" xlink:href = "#circle/>
</svg>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't quite do it like that, but if you're willing to consider other options here's a way to get a similar visual result:

```
<svg class="pie">
    <defs>
        <g id="pie">
            <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="80" stroke-dasharray="none"/>
            <path id="p" transform="rotate(90, 115, 115)" d="
                M 115, 115
                m -80, 0
                a 80,80 0 1,0 160,0
                a 80,80 0 1,0 -160,0
                " />
        </g>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#pie" stroke-dashoffset="52"/>
</svg>
<svg class="pie">
    <use xlink:href="#pie" stroke-dashoffset="125.5"/>
</svg>
<svg class="pie">
    <use xlink:href="#pie" stroke-dashoffset="300"/>
</svg>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNDDr/) or [this page](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/path/piecharts.html). You could also use CSS for setting the `stroke-dashoffset` values on the <use> elements.

In my example each pie diagram is also transparent in the middle, as you can see from the lime green page background. The rotate transform on the path is there to get the start of the stroke to begin at 12 o'clock.

Comment: Very nice!
I could even reuse it and define a different color style
`<svg class="pie2">
    <use xlink:href="#pie" stroke-dashoffset="-145"/>
</svg>`

`svg.pie2 {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
}
svg.pie2 circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 70px;
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me to keep the inline used SVG of a tree with lots of leafs intact. just add a <svg>path of leaf</svg> and then some text. However every single leaf has a unique id and one class for hovering. The hovering over the leaf seems lost. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No. That isn't possible.  If the paths are different you aren't really reusing them.

If you had two occurrences of the same sector angle, just different positions in the circle, you could reuse the first one just with a different rotation.  But that's as near as you are going to get.